# Inline block css fails to make the element full width

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I want to make a class full bleed but I cant.

Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="main-class">
  <div class="background">
    <p>some info in the background</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Some random content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css :

```
.main-class{
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.background{
  margin: -20px;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: inline-block; // must use inline-block
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content{
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

and here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uumkjLy8/1/

the background class must be full bleed with background but as seen in the demo there is white space on the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background element is inside of an element that has padding, meaning it can only extend the full width if you do some sort of "cheesy" method to extend it outside of its parent element (width > 100%, etc).

Your negative margin is not going to fix the width because it is only *moving* the div, not enlarging it. With 100% width and a parent that has padding, it will *never* fully cover its parent's width.

See this fiddle please: https://jsfiddle.net/uumkjLy8/6/

I've removed the padding from `.main-class`, as well as the negative margins on your `.background`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `box sizing` from `.background`

https://jsfiddle.net/uumkjLy8/8/

Comment: That is a terrible solution and will give the OP a horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the padding: -20px at the .background class. Furthermore, add a padding: 20px to the .content class in order to be lined-up with .background

Answer (score -1):

This can be straightforward as:

```css
.main-class {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.content,
.background {
    padding: 20px;
}
.background {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-class">
  <div class="background">
    <p>some info in the background</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Some random content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

...unless you are forced to use some of that redundant CSS...
In such case state that in your question.

Comment: Ah OK. I'm just incredibly curious about reasoning for downvoting here :)
So do you really need all those CSS rules you post, or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I think someone has their downvote machine running, they downvoted the question too, thanks for the help :P

Comment: No probs. Simplify your CSS if you can.From what I can see, you can leave most of it out. Untouched `div's` are block level elements, and as such, they will fill out all horizontal space available.